# Are Bandai "Figmes" compatible with LEGO?

Tags: minifigures, compatibility, clone-brands

According to [gizmodo](http://toyland.gizmodo.com/bandai-desperately-wants-you-to-think-these-dragonball-1750445877) Bandai is releasing a new line of "Figmes" that look astounding similar to our beloved [minifig](/questions/tagged/minifig)s.  Here is the set:

[image: figmes1]

And here is one close up:

[image: figmes2]

Close up the hands look even better, but the legs look a little mushy.

So:

- Does anybody have an early "Figme" or do we have to wait for March?
- Can you test it with genuine LEGO for fit?
- Can we get a side-by-side picture with a legit minifig?
- What do the bottoms and backs look like?

Comment: From https://www.reddit.com/r/dbz/comments/4c7jmb/lego_like_official_dbz_bandai_figme_cant_find/? it sounds like these are only available in Japan and they lack the holes in the back of the legs.

Answer (score 3):

#### Yes, they fit!

With a little research I have learned that the hands can hold standard bar pieces, and the legs are compatible with studs.
However, sitting won't work, and pieces can't be swapped for minifigure parts.

The backs look like the front, solid printed plastic.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the layout, it would probably fit with normal Lego sets and bricks, because the same goes with mega block figures. Although they won't fit in closed spaces where there is only a 1 x 1 space, in general, if you have space, they will fit. Also, with those legs being just about the same as those of Lego minifigs, they would probably fit right in. Another question that might show up is, do you know if there are slots in the back of their legs so they can sit? The layout is the same, I guess, but everybody LOVES minifigs that can sit and actually stay there (in this case, mega block figs can't stay), right? Just kidding, not everybody does, but are there holes in the back of the legs?

Answer (score 1):

These minifigures would definitely fit with lego, just like other companies, such as mega bloks and kreo. As Chicks stated though, they may not be able to sit down. Also, as a warning, these minifigures have very poor paint.